# How to manipulate a Map in flutter?

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

I have the following Map from a JSON static file. I would like to change parts of this Map and then rewrite to File.

The below is an example of the **Map.toString()**

```
{section: {group1: {name: bob, pets: ['dog', 'cat', 'hamster']}}}
```

I would like to add another group to the existing section however I seem to be stuck, I am using the following to read the JSON file and create the Map.

```
Map<String, dynamic> existingContent = json.decode(file.readAsStringSync());
```

However, the best I can do is to list the `existingContent.keys` which shows me the "group1" that is already there, but I can't seem to add a new group. The group name would be the next available number eg.. group2.

Any ideas?

Comment: existingContent['section']['group2'] = {'name': 'bob2', 'pets': ['dog2', 'cat2', 'hamster2']}};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to add something is just to put it directly into the map. (meaning you don't use something like add() as you would in a list.  Here's a simple example:

```
main(){
  Map<String,String> mapped = {'xyz': '1', 'ABC': '1'};
  mapped['another'] = 'beer';  // <-- this is where the new key:value is added.
  print(mapped); // this would give "xyz": "1", "ABC": "1", "another":"value"
}
```

So, for your specific example, you could add one more layer and do it as so:

```
existingContent['section']['group2'] = {'name': 'fred', 'pets': ['dog', 'bird']}};
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

```
String lastKey = existingContent['section'].keys.last;

int index = int.parse(lastKey.substring(lastKey.length-1));

String nextKey = lastKey.substring(0,lastKey.length-1) + (index+1).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tweak this a bit to use keys.length instead, but it definitely helped.